# Is there a way to merge non-moderator accounts into a moderator account?

Tags: support, user-accounts, moderators, merge-accounts, multiple-accounts

It's not a huge deal but I was wondering if it is in some way possible to merge unregistered users with moderator accounts. I found a few old questions/answers (for example, [this is mine](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/787/514)) that I posted either before I had an account or because I wasn't at my home computer and just posted anonymously, and it would be nice to edit/update them.

Just curious if there might be a workaround (i.e., send a request to an admin, delete account then merge?, etc.)

Comment: He is moderator on the [Phylosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/about) site, and the link is for a question on that site.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - It's quicker to use the `[philosophy.se]`  shorthand for that; it produces: [philosophy.se], and plus you avoid misspellings if it links properly :)

Comment: @KevinVermeer The link is for the about page. `:)` I don't know how I achieved to write _phylosophy_ instead of _philosophy_, but I would have done the same error writing `[phylosophy.se]`. `:)` Thank you for reminding me of that shorthand; it comes useful when I have to comment about Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Also, it bears noting that mods should not use their mod privileges to do things with their accounts that other users could not do (changing names too often, editing old comments you wouldn't otherwise edit, deleting/undeleting your own answers, etc).  This seems a little different, but things like posting anonymously and later associating them with yourself are a little sketchy.  It's safter and better to flag the post and let someone else handle it.

Comment: Anyone can delete/undelete their own answers, you don't have to be a moderator to do that. But yes, it might be best to flag another moderator to handle this, just to be on the safe side and keep any blood off your hands. For fun, I tried it too, and get this: `Merge Validation failed for Philosophy: Philosophy, reason: User Id = 514 is a moderator and cannot be the target of a merge`. Confirms the answers so far, you need a dev to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I tired, but I couldn't resist.  You'll need to email team@stackoverflow, or @ one of the team members in TL.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the devs have to do this.  I wasn't able to merge an unregistered account into myself, [getting this error](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19960/what-is-my-lcd-density/19962#comment23102_19962):

> Unable to merge because either the master Account.Id=238697 or merge Account.Id=1281647 have high reputation users on other sites; developers have been notified and will handle this merge.

I would assume this would still be the case if I didn't have lots of rep on another site.  As an aside, it's been awhile so I should probably contact the devs directly :P

Comment: "developers have been notified and will handle this merge" = "you have been added to the suspicious users list" :P

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem of merging two accounts on a site where I am moderator, and where the second account was created by me today, from the usual computer I use when I connect to Stack Exchange, to test what users with unregistered accounts see.
I was going to keep the moderator account (of course), and the only problem I got when merging is that I have associated some high reputation accounts. The error message said that a developer would do the merge. I am not sure how much time it takes for them to merge the accounts, but I think they would be check the log and see my try to merge the accounts.

Comment: Ahh ok. For me the error was just that it's not possible and the script aborted.